# Reactjs Button Not Firing

Tags: reactjs

I have recently taught myself javascript, react, and nodejs. I am having an issue where the submit button is not working but the other buttons I have are working.I am using Chrome as my browser and I have tested it in Firefox as well but I still is not working. Currently when the button is pressed it fully resets the state.

I have tried passing the function as a arrow function, a reference to the function, moving the button outside the child, moving inside the child using props. Everything but writing the function in the child.

```
handleDocs = async () =>{
        console.log('Handle Docs')
        var x = this.state
        if(x.Status==='Approved'){
            var vendorList = []
            var i = 0
            await Axios.get('/staff/'+x['Credit Officer']).then(staff =>{
                x['Credit Officer'] = staff.data[0]['First Name'] + ' ' + staff.data[0]['Last Name']
                    Axios.get('/staff/'+ x['Second Approval']).then(response =>{
                    x['Second Approval'] = response.data[0]['First Name'] + ' ' + response.data[0]['Last Name']          
                    Axios.get('/staff/'+x.application['BDO']).then(response =>{
                        x.application['BDO'] = response.data[0]['First Name'] + ' ' + response.data[0]['Last Name']
                        Axios.post('/genCreditApproval/'+x.AppId, x).then(()=>{
                            Axios.get('return-CreditApproval/'+x.AppId, {responseType: 'blob'}).then((res)=>{
                                const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'applicaiton/pdf'})
                                saveAs(pdfBlob, x.companyInfo['Company Name'] + ' Credit Aproval.pdf')
                            })

                        })
                        Axios.post('/genCreditScoreCard/'+x.AppId, x).then(()=>{
                            Axios.get('return-CreditScoreCard/'+x.AppId, {responseType: 'blob'}).then((res)=>{
                                const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
                                saveAs(pdfBlob, x.companyInfo['Company Name'] + ' Score Card.pdf')
                            })

                        })
                        if(this.state.source['Source Class']===1){
                            Axios.post("/genCreditApprovalTransmittal/"+x.AppId, x).then(()=>{
                                Axios.get('/return-CreditApprovalTransmittal/'+x.AppId, {responseType: 'blob'}).then((res)=>{
                                    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
                                    saveAs(pdfBlob, x.companyInfo['Company Name'] + ' Approval Transmittal.pdf')
                                })
                            })
                            Axios.post("/genDocRequestForm/"+this.state.AppId, x).then(()=>{
                                Axios.get("/return-DocRequestForm/"+ this.state.AppId).then((res)=>{
                                    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
                                    saveAs(pdfBlob, x.companyInfo['Company Name'] + ' Doc Request Form.pdf')
                                })
                            })
                        }
                        else if(this.state.source['Source Class']===2){
                            Axios.post("/genCreditApprovalTransmittalDiscounter/"+this.state.AppId, x).then(()=>{
                                Axios.get('/return-CreditApprovalTransmittal/'+x.AppId, {responseType: 'blob'}).then((res)=>{
                                    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
                                    saveAs(pdfBlob, x.companyInfo['Company Name'] + ' Approval Transmittal.pdf')
                                })
                            })
                            Axios.post("/genFundingCoverSheet/"+this.state.AppId, x).then(()=>{
                                Axios.get("/return-FundingCoverSheet/"+this.state.AppId,x).then((res)=>{
                                    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
                                    saveAs(pdfBlob, x.companyInfo['Company Name'] + ' Funding Cover Sheet.pdf')
                                })
                            })
                        }


                    })
                })
            })
        }
    }

render() {
        if(this.state.stage === 0){
            return this.renderCredit();
        }else if(this.state.stage === 1){
            return <Additional nextStage={this.handleNext} handleText={this.handleAdditionalText} handleChange={this.handleAdditional} credit={this.state}  />
        }
        else{
            return <div>
                {this.scoreCard()}
                <br/>
                <button className="btn btn-sm btn-success" onClick={this.handleDocs}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        }
    }

}
```

I expect to have 4 pdf downloaded after the button is clicked.

Comment: `console.log('Handle Docs')` is this log there in your console ?

Comment: No. It is like the onClick event is not firing and then crashes the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I needed to move the state up. Once I did that the error I had with the component unmounting fixed itself. Simple beginner mistake. Everything works great now. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think your state is changing because you are manipulating the state object directly in your function, change your function as this

```
handleDocs = async () =>{
    console.log('Handle Docs')
    var x = { ...this.state}; // create a copy
    // remaining code
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I saw you are passing the state object directly to other components, please avoid that and see if you are changing the state directly anywhere else

Comment: I have gone through and for every component I have used a copy of the state instead of a direct reference to the state and it still isn't working.

Comment: when you click the button what error do you see on console ?

Comment: I am not seeing an error. It is just going to "home" page (The home page is the parent that controls which, of three, components gets loaded)

Comment: if you can make some sandbox snippet that would help identifying the problem

Comment: I think the issue is stemming from the handleDocs() function. I have gotten some different functions to work.

Comment: yes maybe the issue is in handleDocs, but the minimum example would help identifying the issue

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new you can make your example here at codesandbox